# url option is not working in form_for in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a simple form in rails 4.But url option is not working. I m getting this error
"No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"

My form

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for :article, :url => articles_path do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :text %>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<%end %>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define the method manually after url option:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path, method: :post %>
```

Comment: Even after changing :article to @article , i m getting same error. can u explain me why the above url option is not working?

Comment: @Nagachandra could you, please, add routes.rb to question and controller's create action?

Comment: resources :articles I have added correctly. still issue is not resolved.

Comment: When i click the submit button in form its not going to create action in controller its going to new action. don't know why its working like this.

Comment: Try defining method: :post after url

Answer (score 1):

form_for works using prefix
The route which you want to reach is not having a prefix.
The prefix should have  same name as the name of the controller. 
You can give prefix using **as** attribute in routes file
Then there is no need to give url